# Sending large amounts of data over webservice using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I've dealt somewhat with web services, but I have a client who would like to get a report from our system and display it on their site. What would be the best way to send the information over to them using a web service?

I have two ideas, either do one data transfer that's large, or handle pagination through the web services (though this wouldn't allow filtering.) I'm open to others.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it allow filtering? You can let the customer assign a filter and page the results back using a "hasMorePages" field or something like that. The server can then retrieve the rest of the results and cache it somewhere

Comment: I think their download speed from your server is probably key to choosing the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data is it? Maybe you can provide an [OData feed](http://marknic.com/2010/04/20/CreateAnODataFeedWithVS2008And2010.aspx)? The OData API allows for url-driven filtering, paging, etc.

[More info about WCF Data Services here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106)